# Next timestamp prediction

Tags: python, prediction, forecasting

I want to guess when the event will happen again in dataset.

**For example :** click on film number 3. I want to determine which timestamp to click on this movie again. Can you tell me if you have an idea or code?

Thank you.

Comment: try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.  Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Sketch out the process, looking for the information you need, as a person, at each step.

For example, how many historical timestamps do you need before you can determine a pattern?

It's common to model the time between events using an [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), so what you need is a way to determine your likely λ parameter from the evidence you're collecting in data. It's less a python problem, than a modelling/mathematical one.

The average time between "clicks" is called the expectation, and this is normally expressed as 1/λ. So once you've calculated your average time between clicks, you should, with some basic algebra, be able to arrive at the appropriate λ value to plug into your exponential distribution.

However, if you've already worked out the average time between clicks, you already know the most likely time before the next one! (Assuming you're modelling this as a random process - if you have more in-depth knowledge, you'll need a more complex model)

For a list of values, the way to get the average in python is:

```
average = sum(list) / len(list)
```

But you'll need to convert your data to a series of `time-between-clicks` intervals before putting that into your list.